# Get a graphical representation of a C# code logic - method calls hierarchy

Tags: c#, debugging, architecture, diagram

My actual work consists in some refactoring/code cleanup of parts of a big C# project.

To allow a better understanding of the code logic, and so wich part of the code could be refactorized, I imagine a good way could be to see "graphically" wich methods call wich methods.

If this a good approach ?

And if yes, Is there such a tool ?
The top of the top would be a free tool but if it don't exists, i could make an effort ^^

I came across DebuggerCanvas and something like this but automatic (like using DebuggerCanvas and go into ALL the methods would be the idea)

Thank's by advance.

Comment: Red Gate ANTS Profiler (comes with free trial)

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Didn't think about using a profiler ! 
Eqatec Profiler Free version could do the trick

Comment: Not familiar with Eqatek, but ANTS provides a graphical representation of method calls for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The [Code Map](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/26/introducing-code-map-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-ctp.aspx) functionality added to VS 2012 in Update 1 may be beneficial for this.  It does provide a "canvas" type of functionality which shows how methods are called by other methods.

Comment: Unhopefully I'm actually limited to VS2010, somehing similar for this version maybe ?

Comment: @eka808 Not quite as feature rich, but there's http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2

Comment: Nope this one seems to be just a fancy way of seeing the current code page.

Comment: But i was thinking, what I want is just a methods call hierarchy. Maybe this could be done from scratch by using some code reflection,  roslyn or something similar and something to generate the graph like SVG or HTML5 canvas. Maybe time to investigate !